# Nservice Bus handler trigger issue

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, nservicebus

My project is upgrading to use nservice bus version 7. One of the handler is getting executed concurrently. After analysis found that there is a behavior code written and getting executed after handler election. Then next the handler will get executed.This will executed in loop and not getting ended.

```
public class GatewayPublishBehavior : Behavior<IIncomingLogicalMessageContext>
{

  public override async Task Invoke(IIncomingLogicalMessageContext context, Func<Task> next)
  {
    //// custom logic before calling the next step in the pipeline.
    await next().ConfigureAwait(false); 
    // custom logic after all inner steps in the pipeline completed.
    await context.Publish(context.Message.Instance, 
  this.RetrieveAndGetSendOptions(context));
  }
}
```

Above is the behavior code. Not sure why the handler getting executed multiple times.

Comment: It doesn't look like you posted the full code of the behaviour.

Comment: What @gnud said. The doco for behaviors can be found here : https://docs.particular.net/nservicebus/pipeline/manipulate-with-behaviors

Comment: If you do `await next()` properly and only once, and no other weird behavior, it should not just execute any handler two times for the same message instance.

Comment: @gnud the complete code is as below. public override async Task Invoke(IIncomingLogicalMessageContext context, Func<Task> next)
        {
            //// custom logic before calling the next step in the pipeline.

            await next().ConfigureAwait(false);

            // custom logic after all inner steps in the pipeline completed.

            await context.Publish(context.Message.Instance, this.RetrieveAndGetSendOptions(context));
        }

Comment: @DennisvanderStelt the complete code is as below. public override async Task Invoke(IIncomingLogicalMessageContext context, Func<Task> next)
        {
            //// custom logic before calling the next step in the pipeline.

            await next().ConfigureAwait(false);

            // custom logic after all inner steps in the pipeline completed.

            await context.Publish(context.Message.Instance, this.RetrieveAndGetSendOptions(context));
        }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's exactly like this code

```
public void Whatever()
{
  Whatever();
}
```

An endless loop. Just remove the Publish. Why did you add that line? Do you like duplicates? Because you posted the exact same question twice as well. Trying to create a recursive loop inside StackOverflow?

Comment: I did on the other post.

Comment: Thanks. I have noticed the same. Thanks for your answer

Comment: the context header is getting modified in the behaviour.

Comment: lol @DennisvanderStelt you are silly ... I've seen this question in more places than just SO... Looks to me like folks need to do some reading up on recursion.

Answer (score 0):

Every task need to return something.

```cs
return Task.CompletedTask;
```

Just add the upper given code at the bottom of the Handler. It will solve you problem

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).